# Highcharts while collecting JSON and changing the date by modifying the pointstart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using this chart for showing the data I'm getting through a RestService in this format:

```
  "jsonData": [
      {
        "Resource": "ABC",
        "TimeStamp": "23-07-2017",
        "StatusPercentage": 100
      },
      {
        "Resource": "PQR",
        "TimeStamp": "23-07-2017",
        "StatusPercentage": 100
      },
      {
        "Resource": "XYZ",
        "TimeStamp": "23-07-2017",
        "StatusPercentage": 50
      },
      {
        "Resource": "ABC",
        "TimeStamp": "24-07-2017",
        "StatusPercentage": 100
      },
      {
        "Resource": "PQR",
        "TimeStamp": "24-07-2017",
        "StatusPercentage": 50
      },
      {
        "Resource": "XYZ",
        "TimeStamp": "24-07-2017",
        "StatusPercentage": 100
      }]
```

I'm converting the following into this format for highcharts : 
categories: [23-07-2017, 24-07-2017]
series: [{name: ABC, data: [100,100]}, {name: PQR, data :[100,50]},{name: XYZ, data :[50,100]}]

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 2017
    }
},

series: series: [ {
    name: 'ABC',
    data: [100,50,70],
    timestamp: '23-07-2017'
}, {
    name: 'XYZ',
    data: [50,100,100],
    timestamp: '24-07-2017'
}]
```

});

how can I set my pointstart to be date specific or month specific or year specific in this JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bfhu7suv/
like Pointstart :June or Pointstart: Friday or Pointstart: 23-Jul-2017

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
 xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
```

Series you can write as:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Project Development',
    data: [
      null,
      null,
      [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 3), 12169],
      [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 4), 11269]
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 1), 12908],
      [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 2), 12908],
      [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 3), 2908],
      [Date.UTC(2013, 5, 4), 2208]
    ]
  }]
```

and PlotOptions start point as:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 4, 30)
    }
  },
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/51ozff5w/)</kbd>

Comment: No mate. Didn't help. It's starting from January automatically.

Comment: You can also use pointInterval property (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.pointInterval). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p0khtf6t/.

Comment: oh thanks. helped me. 
I have to change the format of date though. a little.

Comment: @Codey_Boy Generally if answer helped you please upvote and check in as accept "V"